# Postgresql delete on cascade

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have two tables. `Device` and `Device_Config`.
Device table has the following columns:

```
device_id
config_id
bla
bla2
foo
bar
```

And `Device_config` has the following columns

```
id
foo
bar
```

As you can predict, `config_id` on my `Device` table is a foreign key referencing `id` column on the `Device_config` 
So I have added this constraint on my `Device` table.

```
ALTER TABLE device
ADD CONSTRAINT device_config_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (config_id)
REFERENCES device_config (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But this way, when a row in `Device_config` is deleted, the corresponding row on the `Device` table is deleted. However I want the opposite. When a device is deleted, I want the corresponding entry in `device_config` to be deleted. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So several different devices share the same config? I might not understand your business case, but I would have expected the foreign key to point *from* `device_config` *to* `device`, i.e. a `device_id` in the `device_config` table, not the other way round

Comment: Please add the *real* DDLS. IMHO most people read sql faster than your shorthand pseudocode.

Answer (score 4):

then change the logic.
**Device** table wont have *config_id* and **device_config** will have *device_id*.
Relation is one device may have many device_configs.

Then

```
ALTER TABLE device_config
ADD CONSTRAINT device_config_fk FOREIGN KEY (device_id)
REFERENCES config (device_id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE;
```